# How to Repeat Music in Swift

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I would like to know how can I replay my background music forever, right now when the app loads the music begins but when it ends all is quiet, how can I make it to replay all the time.

I am using `AVFoundation Framework`.

Declaration:

```
var BackgroundMusic = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("De_Hofnar_Zonnestraal", ofType: "mp3")!), error: nil)
```

inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
BackgroundMusic.play()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set `numberOfLoops` property to a negative value.

```
backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops = -1
backgroundMusic.play() // To stop, call stop()
```