# How can I repeat a song in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, avaudioplayer, repeat

I am trying to repeat a song in my app. However, it just plays it until the end, then it stops altogether. How can I put in a loop feature for this?

This is my code in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
    do
    {
        let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "APP4", ofType: "mp3")
        try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)

    }

    catch

    {

        //catch error
    }

    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do
    {

        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)

    }

    catch
    {

    }
          player.play()
```

I'm using Xcode 8.

Comment: Maybe you should set category first.

Comment: I think you have to throw notification when song complete and play it again when using AVPlayer.
If you want to use MVMoviePlayer than `moviePlayerController.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;`
`//MPMovieRepeatModeOne <= use for infinite loop`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Repeat Music in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911810/how-to-repeat-music-in-swift)

Comment: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11177333/3687801) with better explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `AVAudioPlayer`'s `numberOfLoops` property for getting the repeat feature.

From the [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1386071-numberofloops)'s Discussion section:

> A value of 0, which is the default, means to play the sound once. Set a positive integer value to specify the number of times to return to the start and play again. For example, specifying a value of 1 results in a total of two plays of the sound. Set any negative integer value to loop the sound indefinitely until you call the 
>   `stop()` method.

So use:

```
player.numberOfLoops = n - 1 // here n (positive integer) denotes how many times you want to play the sound
```

Or, to avail the infinite loop use:

```
player.numberOfLoops = -1
// But somewhere in your code, you need to stop this
```

To stop the playing:

```
player.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `numberOfLoops`

```
player.numberOfLoops = 2 // or whatever
```

From Apple doc:

> var numberOfLoops: Int
>
> The number of times a sound will return to the beginning, upon
>   reaching the end, to repeat playback.

Answer (score 1):

For repeat song you can set the Property numberOfLoops to -1 .It will work as infinity loop

```
player.numberOfLoops = -1
```

Answer (score 1):

With **SwiftySound**, you can do it with a single line of code. All you have to do is pass -1 value for *numberOfLoops* parameter.

```
Sound.play(file: "dog", fileExtension: "wav", numberOfLoops: -1)
```

You can find [SwiftySound](https://github.com/adamcichy/SwiftySound) on GitHub.